# How to get a method produce custom output without modifying the method in the class?

Tags: java

My Java project is organised as follows:

- (package no.1) `it.blabla.myproject` package containing the classes strictly related to my project
- (package no.2) `it.blabla.myproject.utils` package containing some utility classes, some of which I use in package no.1.

I want to keep package no.2 "general" = not related to my project, so I can re-use it for other projects.

Package no.2 contains the following class:

```
...
import org.xml.sax.SaxParseException;
...
// For handling errors in xml parsing
class XmlHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    ...
    //stuff
    ...
    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()+"; "+currentNodeName);     // Here there should be 
                                                                     // a project-specific error message
                                                                     // between the e.getMessage() and
                                                                     // the currentNodeName
    };
    ...
}
```

My problem is: the message returned by this error handler must contain some specific text related to the project (for example: `System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "; the data of Company XYZ are not ok; " + currentNodeName);`)

How could I achieve this without loss of generality of my `utils` package? I know I could just pass a `String` parameter to the method and put my custom error message in it, but it's kinda ugly...

Since I am quite new to Java, I'd like to understand how this could be implemented properly. Do you see anything wrong or not fulfilling best-practices in my project structure?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I could also create another class named for example `CustomHandler extends XmlHandler`, the problem is: should I create it in package 1 or 2? Some other classes in package 2 use `XmlHandler` in turn, so I should modify also them in order to use `CustomHandler`... but then the utils package will again loose its generality

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Inheritance. You see how the `XmlHandler extends DefaultHandler` and then overrides the error method? You can do the same thing in you project-specific implementation by creating, for example, a CustomXmlHandler which extends the XmlHandler

```
class CustomXmlHandler extends XmlHandler {
    
    ...
    
    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        // Your custom error handling
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question to cover another issue about this...

Comment: Then you might want to look into dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks, what if I create an interface XmlHandler in utility package and then implement it elsewhere? Is this a good practice?